# R Access first element of the list while using loop and append it into a vector

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a function that gives results as shown.

```
List of 3
 $ D1: num 0.0509
 $ D2: num 0.0536
 $ D : num 0.0523
```

I want to access the first element of the list, and put all the values in a vector. It loops through the data in the following way.
Vector1 and Vector2 have around 100 data.

A sample of data

```
vector1=c(1213, 57683, 74466, 44419, 17481, 3403, 42252, 7045,29445, 15004, 21337, 1892, 21861, 238, 26574, 17579)

vector2=c(3185, 29692, 12570, 26081, 4992, 1659, 16592, 1748, 37583, 6751, 10188, 355, 8116, 9, 5064, 1846)
```

It loops through the data in the following way.

```
w<-2
ab <- c()
for (i in w:length(vector1)){
  pred[[count]] <- vector1[(i-w+1):i]
  obs[[count]] <- vector2[(i-w+1):i]
  
  a1 <- pred[count]
  a2<- obs[count]
  count = count + 1
  klvalue(unlist(a1),unlist(a2))
  a1 <- list()
  a2<- list()
  kldta<-append(klvalue,ab) 
}
```

The function is as shown

```
klvalue<- function(a,b){kl.dist(a, b, base = exp(1))
  }      #kl.dist is from library(seewave)
```

I know I can access the data in the last by doing  `klvalue[[1]]` but I'm not really sure how to do it in a loop.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to get all the values of ```$D1``` into a single vector.

Comment: Now post the results of `dput(your_list)`

Comment: I'm having that issue. I am not able to store the results or rather don't know how to store the results of the list.

Comment: post the results in your question. Not in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood, but is this your intended outcome?

```r
#install.packages("seewave")
library(seewave)

klvalue<- function(a,b){kl.dist(a, b, base = exp(1))
}      #kl.dist is from library(seewave)

vector1=c(1213, 57683, 74466, 44419, 17481, 3403, 42252, 7045,29445, 15004, 21337, 1892, 21861, 238, 26574, 17579)
vector2=c(3185, 29692, 12570, 26081, 4992, 1659, 16592, 1748, 37583, 6751, 10188, 355, 8116, 9, 5064, 1846)

w<-2
ab <- list()
pred <- list()
obs <- list()
count <- 1
kldta <- list()

for (i in w:length(vector1)){
  pred[[count]] <- vector1[(i-w+1):i]
  obs[[count]] <- vector2[(i-w+1):i]
  
  a1 <- pred[count]
  a2 <- obs[count]
  count <- count + 1
  klval <- klvalue(unlist(a1),unlist(a2))
  kldta[i] <- klval[[1]]
}

kldta_final <- unlist(kldta)
kldta_final
#>  [1] 0.0475256543 0.1523148191 0.1896899344 0.0468433690 0.0219116189
#>  [6] 0.0017162112 0.0115640592 0.1471657288 0.1053351614 0.0004260342
#> [11] 0.0253701967 0.0141622162 0.0148801420 0.0072153100 0.0403388718
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>